# Find and show unique value from bash array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

If I have an array in bash like:

`x=(1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5)`

How do you determine and print the value that occurs only once?

Comment: In Bash 4.0+, you have associative arrays. Just loop once and use an associative array to keep the count of each value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
printf "%s\n" "${x[@]}" | sort | uniq -u
```

Output:

```
4
```